# Shared libraries and convenience when compiling

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

## Context

I'm new to making libraries, and I'm trying to make a shared library. I made `libfoo.so` and stored in in `<path>/bin/shared` directory. My library has some headers `h1.hpp`... which are stored in `<path>/src/include`.

### Header files

Right now, when I try to compile `bar.cpp` from another environment, I run

`g++ -L<path>/bin/shared bar.cpp -o bar -lfoo`

but it says `fatal error: h1.hpp: No such file or directory`. The only way I can compile it is if I add

`-I<path>/src/include`

when compiling. Is there something I can do differently to avoid users of my library having to add this `-I` flag?

### rpath

I also realize that users of my library would need to add

`-Wl, -rpath=<path>/bin/shared`

when compiling their programs. Is this something I can expect my users to figure out themselves or is there something I can do to make using the library more convenient?

Comment: Setting include path is a common requirement, no matter whether the library is distributed as a shared object, static archive, or header-only.  Build systems usually have some tool to help manage include and link paths, such as [`pkg-config`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config), and OS package managers are supposed to setup the build system correctly during installation of the library.

Comment: *"Is there something I can do differently to avoid users of my library having to add this -I flag?"* - Users of your library need to know where your library headers are for them to `#include` them. This is normal for *any* consumed library where headers are not already installed in a header location default-included in the preprocessor include paths. In short, they're not going to find your headers by way of magic.

Comment: Use some kind of build system. [CMake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/index.html) is an option that's widely used. If you provide the appropriate configuration files with the installation of your package, you may end up with the user just having to to `find_package(YourPackageName) target_link_libraries(TheirTarget PRIVATE YourLib)` in addition to providing the location of your installation during configuration...